# My input label is overlapping the other label

Tags: html, css

My first input label is in the correct place but my second one (Last Name) is overlapping the First name one. How can i correct this? I have tried removing the position:absolute from .itemForm label but this doesn't work cause I want the label to be located on top of the user's input.

```css
    .lineForm {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.itemForm {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.itemForm input,
.itemForm select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 26px 16px 10px 16px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    border-radius: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222222;
}

.itemForm label {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7B7B7B;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentForm">
                <div class="lineForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <div>
                            <input id="firstname" name="Firstname" type="text" class="formInput" required="">
                            <label for="nome">First name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input id="lastname" name="Lastname" type="text" class="formInput" required="">
                            <label for="sobrenome">Last Name</label>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <input id="tel" name="Telefone" value="(21) 00000-0000" type="tel" required="">
                        <label>Telefone</label>
                    </div>                     
                </div>        
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `position: relative` to the parent `div`

```
.itemForm > div {
  position: relative; 
}
```

```css
.lineForm {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.itemForm {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.itemForm > div {
  position: relative; 
}

.itemForm input,
.itemForm select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 26px 16px 10px 16px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    border-radius: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222222;
}

.itemForm label {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7B7B7B;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentForm">
                <div class="lineForm">
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <div>
                            <input id="firstname" name="Firstname" type="text" class="formInput" required="">
                            <label for="nome">First name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input id="lastname" name="Lastname" type="text" class="formInput" required="">
                            <label for="sobrenome">Last Name</label>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemForm">
                        <input id="tel" name="Telefone" value="(21) 00000-0000" type="tel" required="">
                        <label>Telefone</label>
                    </div>                     
                </div>        
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.itemForm label {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7B7B7B;
    position: absolute; /* <- this is why! */
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given **position: absolute** to labels. But you didn't gave **position: relative** to their parent div's. Add CSS:-

```
.itemForm > div{
   position: relative;
 }
```